# React router - pass props on routes to child components

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Can someone please tell me the best way to do this? I would like to pass a page title prop from my route into my header child component. Here are my routes:

```
var sampleApp= React.createClass({

render: function (){
    return (
        <div className="our-schools-app">
            <Header />
            <RouteHandler />
            <Footer />
        </div>
    );
},

});

var routes = (
<Route name="app" path="/" handler={OurSchoolsApp}>
    <DefaultRoute name="home" handler={HomePage}  />
    <Route name="add-school" handler={AddSchoolPage}  />
    <Route name="calendar" handler={CalendarPage}  />
    <Route name="calendar-detail" path="calendar-detail/:id" handler={CalendarDetailPage} />
    <Route name="info-detail" path="info-detail/:id" handler={InfoDetailPage} />
    <Route name="info" handler={InfoPage} />
    <Route name="news" handler={NewsListPage} />
    <Route name="news-detail" path="news-detail/:id" handler={NewsDetailPage} />
    <Route name="contacts" handler={ContactPage} />
    <Route name="contact-detail" handler={ContactDetailPage} />
    <Route name="settings" handler={SettingsPage} />
</Route>
);


Router.run(routes, function(Handler){
var mountNode = document.getElementById('app');
React.render(<Handler /> , mountNode);
});
```

I would like to pass the title of my page in the route as a prop like this:

```
<Route name="info" handler={InfoPage} pageTitle="Info Page" />
```

To my header component:

```
var Header = React.createClass({

render: function () {
    return (
            <div className="bar bar-header"
                style={this.getStyle()}>
                 <HomeButton />
                 <div className="h1 title">{this.props.pageTitle}</div>
            </div>
    )
}
});
```

But the props show as empty, can anyone help?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can't currently (pre 1.0) do that with React Router. I believe one recommended way is to have wrapper components:

```
var BaseComponent = React.createClass({
     render: function() {
        return <p>{this.props.text}</p>
     }
});

var FancyComponent = React.createClass({
     return <BaseComponent text="fancy!" />
});

var EvenFancierComponent = React.createClass({
     return <BaseComponent text="SUPER fancy!" />
});
```

Then these routes:

```
<Route name="standard" handler={BaseComponent} />
<Route name="fancy" handler={FancyComponent} />
<Route name="superfancy" handler={EvenFancierComponent} />
```

However there's a discussion on this topic on the [React Router github issues](https://github.com/rackt/react-router/issues/615) which provides good news:

> I just wanted to note here that in the new API (see [#1158](https://github.com/rackt/react-router/pull/1158)) routes are
>   just plain objects, so you can put whatever props you want on them.
>   Your transition hooks will get a route arg and components will receive
>   this.props.route, so you should be good to go.

It looks like that new 1.0 release is in beta and so should be coming fairly soon!

Answer (score 10):

I just had the same problem and found [this answer](https://github.com/reactjs/react-router/issues/1531#issuecomment-146514399) in the React Router GitHub issues.

It suggests to pass the `props` to the `Route` component and access them from the component with `this.props.route.*`.

I just used if for my own application and find it very easy to use. (**Especially easier than the accepted answer**) This is the example from the answer (thanks to [anjdreas](https://github.com/anjdreas)):

**Routing:**

```
React.render((
  <Router>
    <Route path="/" component={RootComp} myprop="foo">
        <Route path="foo" component={FooComp}>
           <Route path="bar" component={BarComp} />
        </Route>
    </Route>
  </Router>
), document.getElementById('example'));
```

**Component:**

```
class RootComp extends React.Component {
    render: {
        this.props.route.myprop // == "foo"
    }
}
```

Comment: Why is `this.props.route` undefined on my child component? I have the exact same thing.

Comment: I am also getting undefined `this.props.route` while console its value

Answer (score 4):

If you are using ES6, then it is also rather nice to inline a [stateless functional component](https://medium.com/@housecor/react-stateless-functional-components-nine-wins-you-might-have-overlooked-997b0d933dbc) using [ES6 arrow syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)...

```
<Route name="info" handler={()=> <InfoPage pageTitle="Info Page" />} />
```

If your handler component cares about routed `params` or some other aspect of the route then be sure to pass down the `props`.

```
<Route name="info" handler={(props)=> <InfoPage pageTitle="Info Page" {...props} /> } />
```

Comment: Thank's for mention `props` case, without it router not worked for me.

Comment: For React Router v4 use `render` instead of `handler`.