# How to pass props to react-router 1.0 components?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

**Please note, that although the question itself is largely a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30871070/react-router-pass-props-on-routes-to-child-components), it concerns a different version which *should* support this. The linked question already accepted an answer on an old version**

I'm pretty confused about what the intended workflow is.

Let's say I have a menu system where clicking on each item uses react-router to navigate to an area which pulls some data from the server.

```
url: yoursite/#/lists/countries
----------------------------
Billing Codes | <<Countries>> | Inventory Types 
---------------------------------------------------------
Countries:
---------------
Afghanistan
Azerbaijan
Belarus
```

with routes something like

```
Route #/lists component: Lists
   Route billing-codes component: BillingCodes
   Route countries component: Countries
   Route inventory-types component: InventoryTypes
```

I don't want to preload data from the server until an area is navigated to, so in my `Countries` component's on `componentWillMount` I fire an event (I'm using reflux but...whatever) that triggers a store to do an ajax request and update itself with the current list of countries.

Now the `Countries` component reacts to that change in state by updating the countries in its props. Except - reasonably - that generates an invariant error because I shouldn't be updating props on a child component, I should update it at the top level. But the top level is the router itself so now I'm just lost - where *am* I supposed to listen to changes and update props from?

([Cross-posted to the issue tracker](https://github.com/rackt/react-router/issues/1472) as I think it needs some clearer documentation)

Comment: possible duplicate of [React router - pass props on routes to child components](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30871070/react-router-pass-props-on-routes-to-child-components)

Comment: Appreciate it, but I *am* using 1.0 and still don't get it. Would be happy to see an answer on the original question or on here, though the original one seems to have an answer (now outdated) already accepted.

Comment: I asked similar question a while ago http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31168014/pass-object-through-link-in-react-router I gave some of the ideas to the problem, but don't have a clear answer yet

Comment: You're using 1.0 of react-router? It's not even out yet and there's little documentation. There is a workaround in my suggested duplicate.

Comment: its  out on npm in beta2. There's docs inside their docs directory on github. I adjusted the topic to clarify that I'm specifically looking for the intended workflow in 1.0

Comment: @ColinRamsay in addition, looking at your workaround answer - I'm not sure I understand how that helps when adjusting props after the fact like in my specific situation. Isn't that exactly what is generating the invariant error?

Answer (score 3):

Reading the [react-router 0.13 -> 1.0 Upgrade Guide](https://github.com/rackt/react-router/blob/master/UPGRADE_GUIDE.md) and [this example](https://github.com/rackt/react-router/tree/master/examples/passing-props-to-children) led me to the following:

```
{ this.props.children && 
     React.cloneElement(this.props.children, {newprop: this.state.someobject }) }
```

Instead of including the child components directly, we clone them and inject the new properties. (The guard handles the case where there is no child component to be rendered.) Now, when the child component renders, it can access the needed property at `this.props.newprop`.

Comment: This approach is causing an error on the page load if either of the propTypes of the Route component are configured to be required.

Answer (score 1):

The easy way is to just use `this.state`, but if you absolutely have to use `this.props` then you should probably extend `Router.createElement`.

First add the `createElement` prop to your `Router` render.

```js
React.render(
  <Router history={history} children={Routes} createElement={createElement} />,
  document.getElementById('app')
);
```

Wrap all of your components in a new `Container` component.

```js
function createElement(Component, props) {
    return <Container component={Component} routerProps={props} />;
}
```

Your `Container` component will probably look something like this. Pass an `onLoadData` function down to your component.

```js
import React from 'react';
import _ from 'lodash';

class Container extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { props: props.routerProps };
  }

  onLoadData(props) {
    var mergedProps = _.merge(this.state.props, props);
    this.setState({ props: mergedProps });
  }

  render() {
    var Component = this.props.component;
    return <Component {...this.state.props} onLoadData={this.onLoadData.bind(this)} />;
  }
}
```

Then from your loaded component, when you get your data back from the server, just fire `this.props.onLoadData(data)` and the data will be merged with your current props.

[Read the `Router.createElement` Documentation](http://rackt.github.io/react-router/tags/v1.0.0-beta3.html#-createelement-component-props-)

Comment: Actually, you might be able to just use something like lodash to merge your incoming data with your `this.props`, depending on the complexity.